# _OBJC_CLASS_$_ - symbol(s) not found error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I create a new application for iPad starting from an UISplitView application that works correctly, in the new application I get this error:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ConcertListController", referenced from:
objc-class-ref-to-ConcertListController in RootViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What it mean? How can I solve?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you need to link in whatever framework ConcertListController is a part of.  Try going to the project window, right click on frameworks and choose add existing framework .... you should be able to find the framework including ConcertListController there.

Comment: Or, if that class isn't part of a library, make sure it's included in the project's Compile Sources build phase.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem. My solution was remove the reference and re added those files. Then it will show a window and make sure to tick on "Add to target" check box.